# couchdb - retrieve unique documents for a view that emits non-unique two array keys

Tags: filter, pagination, couchdb, mapreduce

I have an map function in a view in CouchDB that emits non-unique two array keys, for documents of type `message`, e.g.

[image: 2 array keys]

The first position in the array key is a user_id, the second position represents whether or not the user has read the message.

This works nicely in that I can set `include_docs=true` and retrieve the actual documents.  However, I'm retrieving duplicate documents in that case, as you can see above in the view results.  I need to be able to write a view that can be queried to return unique messages that have been read by a given user. Additionally, I need to be able to efficiently paginate the resultset.

1. notice in the image above that [66, true] is emitted twice for doc id *26a9a271de3aac494d37b17334aaf7f3*.  As far as I can tell, with the keys in my map function, I cannot reduce in such a way that unique documents will be returned.
2. the next idea I had was to emit `doc._id` also in the map function and reduce with `group_level=exact` the result being:

   [image: 3 array keys]

   now I am able to get unique document ids, but I cannot get the documents without doing a second query.  And even in the case of a second query, it will require a lot of complexity to do pagination like this (at least I think so).
3. the last idea I came up with is to emit the entire document rather than the doc._id in the third position in the array key, then I can access the entire document and likely paginate.  This seems really brutish.

### So my question is:

Is **#3** above a terrible idea?  Is there something I'm missing? Is there a better approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please show your map and reduce functions?  It's not clear why you can't change the map function to not emit duplicates.

Comment: @WickedGrey I think that might be the answer....

Comment: @WicketdGrey was correct, The solution to my problem was to ensure that I emitted unique keys.  I did that by keeping track of the keys that were emitted for each document and ensuring I didn't emit one more than once.  That should've been obvious, but I'm learning :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See @WickedGrey's comment to the question.  The solution is to ensure that I never emit the same key twice for one document.  I do this in the **map** function by keeping track of the keys as I emit them in an array, then skipping the emit if the key exists in the array.